# mongoose and restify - localize strings before returning json

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, mongoose, restify

I would like to return  localized Strings for multilanguage business objects in our RestFul API based on node.js, restify and mongoose. I have the requirement to store the translated resources on our translation resource server, but also need to support dynamic creation of those business objects.

I found a solution to easily plugin the i18n process in the POST/PUT calls using a single pre-'save' mongoose middleware on all Schema, when creating or updating my multi-languate business objects - this works because I am able to pass the request context to the obj.save(req, callback) call.

But, I am struggling to plug in the i18n on simple GETs. I thought of and tried different ways where I can plugin the i18n before returning the response, but don't really find a good way. Options I thought of:

- translate in a mongoose middleware pre /post ('init'):

  Problem: I don't have access to the request context, and therefore
  don't know the locale to return, so I cannot translate there.
- translate in the toObject() / toJSON {transform: }:

  Same issue - i don't have the request context in these hooks.
- translate in the handler/controller methods for each ressource.

  Problem: Duplication, I have to do it everywhere, I would really prefer a solution I can define on the model/Schema layer
- translate in a restify / express middleware towards the end:

  Problem: I don't have access to the mongoose schema metainformation anymore, so I don't know which attriutes to translate.

Edit: just found this additional way:
 - translate in a custom restify responseFormatter:

This seems to work nicely, in the reponseformatter I have access to everything I need. It kind of seems a little weird from an architechtural point of view, but if nobody has a better idea, I will add this as an answer.

Maybe (hopefully) I am missing something obvious...

thanks for any hints